# How to POST a pull request comment using BitBucket API in python?

Tags: python, rest, bitbucket

I am trying to add comment to bitbucket pull request through REST API. Response I get is 404 always

First I tried with python requests library, then curl command

```py
#python code
link = 'https://<base-url>/2.0/repositories/<project_name>/views_source/pullrequests/<pull-request-id>/comments'
r = requests.post(link, verify=False)
```

```
#windows command
curl -X POST -d "{\"text\" : \"test comment\"}" https://<base-url>/2.0/repositories/<project_name>/views_source/pullrequests/<pull-request-id>/comments
```

Error I am getting is as follows:-

```
part of python output:
<h2>Oops, you&#39;ve found a dead link</h2>
```

```
curl output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><status><status-code>404</status-code><message>null for uri: https://<base-url>/rest/api/1.0/repositories/<repo-name>/views_source/<comment-id>/comments</message></status>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with Bitbucket REST API 1.0 version.

The API format is as follows:-

- /rest/api/1.0/projects//repos//pull-requests//comments.

Python code used to add comment:

```
import requests
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

commentLink = 'https://base-url//rest/api/1.0/projects/<project_name>/repos/<repo_name>/pull-requests/<pull_request_id>/comments'
res = requests.post(commentLink, verify=False, auth=(username,password), headers=headers, data=json.dumps({'text': <comment>}))
```

Reference to API : [Link](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm8286353872)